# ASP split config files

Tags: asp.net

For a school project we are trying to get our ASP.net project as modular as we can. We want to split up our Web.config so that we have separate files to store our database queries in. One for each "model" to be exact.

I tried to look on the internet for more information about this but I could not really find any good answer to this question that I understood.

So how can we split up queries into separate config files and access them?

Comment: To be clear; you're storing 'queries' in you configuration files? i.e. SELECTS and UPDATES? Why oh why?

Comment: We have learnt to do it this way at school. Storing prepared statements with params.

Comment: Example:
<add key="SELECT_OWN_RECIPES" value="SELECT * FROM Recipes WHERE uid=@uid"/>

Comment: So you are aware, this is not proper design.   You should be creating stored procedures in SQL.   At a minimum, I would keep the database queries in your compiled code as strings.

Comment: So instead of reading the queries from the config file we should just do db.CreateCommand(conn, "QUERY HERE?");

Comment: @Jens: yes, your business logic, and its implementations are not config. They're meant to be compiled into the application.

Comment: @Jens - To add to what p.campbell has said, imagine you change a column (e.g. data type, name etc) in a table used in one of your queries. No matter how you slice it, you will have to go into the code and change how it is consumed. You cannot simply change the query in the config file. In fact, I cannot ever imagine a situation where you could logically change just the config file and not have to touch some other code. Thus, I second the motion that storing queries in a config file is a horrid idea.

Comment: There is the argument here, which many DBA's bring up, in that if you are trying to abstract away how the data is returned, what query is run etc, that you should use a stored procedure. As the app just needs a set of data in a specific format, it doesn't care if it comes from a single table or is joined together from 5. However I think you could argue that one either way

Comment: I can see how this is a design error. This is why we tried to find a way to better organise our queries in the first place. I don't really understand why they would teach us to do it this way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I have to back up what others have said, you really should not be storing queries in your web.config, they should be hardcoded in the apps if you aren't using an ORM.

If you really want to look into having the queries in files and modular files you could look into using resource files. Now these should be used for localisations and things that are considered "resources" however there is no reason why you couldn't put queries into them.

This way you could have one resource file per module. Which is modular as you want.
So given your example you would have a resources file called recipes. Then you would have a key of SelectOwn and the value is then your query. You can then access this in your code behind by saying Recipies.SelectOwn which at least is a nicer API.

I would though double check your home work, is there a reason you can't put queries in your code? Even as constant strings?

Comment: Just for discussion, while I wouldn't put queries in web.config, I like storing them in files in certain situations. It is good for organization and simplifies deployment. I can't think of any substantive downside versus hardcoding them, except perhaps performance, but a simple caching mechanism takes care of that. There's no difference in security if it's just that versus in your code. I suppose one could worry about easier access if your server was hacked, but you've already got much bigger problems in that situation anyway.

Comment: @jamietre: simplifies deployment? Sounds like each .aspx would have its own .config. Yikes. That just doubled the number of files for deployment. This goes against any/all advantages that a proper data layer gives. Maintainability goes down the tubes. This is a DailyWTF candidate. Configuration is meant to be for values that change given changes in environment (timeouts, connection strings, email addresses, LDAP servers, etc.) that could be subject to change. Config is NOT about business logic, which is exactly what SQL is about.

Comment: @jamietre - IMO, there really isn't any reason to store the query string anywhere other than the data access layer routine used to retrieve the information. Properly encapsulated, they shouldn't ever be referenced anywhere other than in the dal method. Thus, storing them in yet another file just makes the next developer's life tougher when they need to make a change.

Comment: No, I'm not making a config file for every single page. Maybe there's one file for each query, and they are just referenced as a path, like 'queries/reports/somereport." Or they could all be in one file, or in a database, whatever. It simplifies deployment because a change to a query doesn't require recompiling the module or even restarting the application. Why would this have any impact on the structure of a data layer, or maintainability? Architecturally, it's nothing more than replacing a string with a function that returns a string.

Comment: Let me be clear that I am not suggesting this as a general purpose methodology. As I said, certain situations, when I have used it is generally for ad-hoc reports. It's just a tool like any other, and while it may not have value in some situations, I can't see any downside other than "there are more files."

Comment: @jamietre - RE: change to query. It is not true that a change to the query will not require recompiling the code. Imagine the query is changed to return multiple rows instead of one row. Imagine it returns fewer columns. The code that uses that query will break. In fact, most changes to the query will require a change to the consuming code.

Comment: @jamietre - By far the biggest reason not to do this is that, as p.campbell said, the query represents business logic. If you change the query in the deployed version of the application, that change never gets into source control.

Comment: @Thomas, your assumption is that every single query in an application describes a class. Personally, I do not create a new class every time someone asks me to give them some report that they can download as an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: @Thomas: "the query represents business logic" Not always. That is my point.

Comment: to further add my thoughts, the only reason I need to change a query is either for performance or if i need to change what data is returned. In these cases I always need to recompile anyway, as I need to ensure the query hasn't broken anything. Both in terms of a compilation error from a rogue unescaped ' or more importantly to run my integration tests which rely on the build copying all the files.

Comment: @Thomas, why would you create new class when all you've been asked to do is provide your user with a data dump of some kind?

Comment: @jamietre - Where did I say that each query maps to a class? It represents logic. To be consumed, you need to reference the columns and have an expectation of the number of rows returned. Reports will be bound to column names. Change those or their data type or rows returned and you will likely break the consuming code.

Comment: So, you can't imagine a routine that accepts an arbitrary dataset, creates an Excel spreadsheet with the same columns, and streams it the the user when they click "Download report?" It sounds like I'm not doing enough work to achive my users' needs.

Comment: @Thomas @jamietre @p.campbell is correct, SQL is always business logic, selecting what data you want returned, order etc is essentially business logic, this shouldn't sit in the presentation or reporting code, although we are verging into another debate. To get back to @Jens original question, regardless of right / wrong, the Config shouldn't do this but resources or even some sort of files like @jamiertre is suggesting will work, its just not write.

Comment: "SQL is always business logic." If you want to see my code that accepts any SQL query and turns it into a spreadsheet, I'd be happy to share it, it's not that complicated. Is this not legitimate? If you had to produce reports fairly often that were just needed as a spreadsheet, why would you do more work to achieve this goal?

Comment: @jamietre - And how does that change to the query you made in the config file get into source control? How does it get deployed when you deploy a new version of your system? How does it get tested?

Comment: How does anything else get into source control? It's a resource in your application like any other. How do you test reports? Do your unit tests tell you if the logic in your SQL is correct, or just if it runs? How would it know what should be returned by a report that is based on arbitrary data?

Comment: @jamietre im not arguing that your code doesn't do what you are saying, but what I am saying is that surely these queries you are running mean and do something. Thus they are business logic, maybe not for the converter but they are in terms of the concept of the report. Surely these queries have to be kept, resued, tested etc.

Comment: @jamietre - I don't think you understand. If the SQL is in a config file, then it can be changed after it is deployed and thus not get into source control. If it is in code, and presuming the rest of the solution is in source control, then the query gets into source control. RE: Unit Test: Actually, sometimes I do write unit tests to test reports to ensure that certain assumptions about what should be returned are true. For example, that each row represents what I think it should represent.

Comment: @jamietre - If all of these queries are truly ad hoc and designed purely to spit out columns on an Excel report, then you might as well store the SQL statement in a table in the database with a report name. I.e., only store queries related to the logic of the application in the dal (definitely not a config file) and have a table of "reports" that contains the SQL statements used to generate your Excel reports.

Comment: It's a resource, it's stored in source control. It's just a file. An aspx is also a file, you can also change that without recompiling, yet I think you'd consider that part of the source. I really don't think we're talking about the same situations here. Maybe this just doesn't come up for you. If I had to create a fully fleshed out data object for every single report I was asked to do, sometimes involving 50 or more fields, I'd kill myself. If someone asked you to just run some simple random report, would you just do it, or write a ton of code and get back to them hours/days later?

Comment: @jamietre - Again, the question is whether the query relates to the application, a specific report as part of the application or an ad hoc report. For the first two, I would want that in source control. In source control, you can keep track of who changed a query and how they changed it. If it is ad hoc, it doesn't belong in the application in the first place. For queries related to the functioning of the application, those should simply be in the dal in code.

Comment: @jamietre - Somehow you have it in your head that when I say the (non-ad hoc) query belongs in code that I also mean you must make a class from its results. I do not mean that. I've seen plenty of applications using the transaction script design model where they simply passed DataTables around. However, the SQL statement should still be in code in source control.

Comment: I want to know if a report's changed, so I would likely track database changes to something that produces a report. Source control manages lots of things that aren't code, like content, styles, templates, etc.. unless you're using some utopian CMS that isolates every byte that isn't actually logic. I understand your position, but it's a principle. In the real world (mine, anyway) I have to make decisions about whether doing something the absolute right way is better overall than getting something done faster because deadlines and cost are more important than perfection that only I know about.

Comment: @jamietre - In your real world are you the only person that will ever work on those queries until the end of time? If a table is changed on which multiple reports might be based and it isn't discovered until a deadline looms, how do you determine who changed what and the nature of the change? There is more to development than the immediate deadline. Design your systems so that you can hand them off to another developer. If you win the lottery and leave, think about the next developer that has to figure out why a report doesn't work because the day will come when you are the next person.

Comment: @jamietre - Btw, if you put the reports in the database, then a proper backup procedure ensures you can recover previous versions of a report stored in data.

Comment: These comments are getting a little off-topic from the original question. Whether storing your SQL queries in config/resources/DAL/etc. is really bad will depend largely on exactly what your system is, what the queries do, how you manage change/deployment and general preferences. If you guys can't agree which is "best", how is the original poster going to decide? ;) The most important thing is to you focus on writing code **you** can test and maintain. There is no *right* answer. Focus on writing software that works first. This is interesting: http://www.codethinked.com/starting-a-new-chapter

Comment: @DanTup - Danny Tuppeny - Granted, there is no *right* answer, but there is a nearly unlimited number of answers that are, to be kind, decidedly suboptimal. Storing queries in a config file, IMO, would qualify as one of those suboptimal solutions. Thus, it makes sense to discuss alternate solutions once it is clear that the systemic approach behind original question will create more problems than it is worth.

Comment: @Thomas - I agree, and I don't think anyone is debating that. However, the "best" way is totally subjective and I don't think the people posting in these comments will ever agree, so the debate seems pointless, especially given it doesn't actually answer the asked question ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you organize your pages into folders you can have a web.config file in each folder.  All pages in that folder will be able to use that web.config file.

Comment: it all depends on what sections in the web.config you want to use... not all sections support inheriting through subfolders, some only support it in subapplications and other sections dont support it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge multiple web.configs like this at runtime. You could possibly merge some files at build time with a post build action. If you really wanted to go this route, you'd be better using your own config files instead of web.config and load them within your application. That said - why do you need separate files? Can't you just group them up in the web.config?

Anyway, as others have hinted, this is probably the wrong place to be storing SQL queries. I would query this with your tutor. The usual place for SQL is the data access classes or Stored Procedures (personally I dislike these, as testing newer versions of the software side-by-side becomes difficult if you have logic in the database).